# Error while executing the scripts using Karate Framework when integrated with QMetry

Tags: qaf

I am getting below error while executing the scripts in Karate Framework.I have integrated QMetry with this Karate Framework. Followed this link to integrate with QMetry.

http://www.qmetry.com/resources/videos/qmetry-test-manager-for-jira-test-automation-training/

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPool.setValidateAfterInactivity(I)V
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:182)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:164)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:971)
at com.intuit.karate.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient.makeHttpRequest(ApacheHttpClient.java:302)
at com.intuit.karate.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient.makeHttpRequest(ApacheHttpClient.java:82)
at com.intuit.karate.http.HttpClient.invoke(HttpClient.java:207)
at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.method(StepDefs.java:312)
at ✽.When method get(MyService/GetService.feature:8)

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat$Value.empty()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat$Value;
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig.<clinit>(MapperConfig.java:49)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:558)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:474)
    at com.infostretch.qmetrytestmanager.helper.ResultUploadHelper.uploadResultToServer(ResultUploadHelper.java:70)
    at com.infostretch.qmetrytestmanager.result.TestExecution.close(TestExecution.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions$1.invoke(RuntimeOptions.java:294)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.close(Unknown Source)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.JUnitReporter.close(JUnitReporter.java:232)
    at com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate.run(Karate.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Could you please help me on below if you have some time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555929/debug-db-validation-run-new-feature-with-demotestparallel-java

Comment: I'm the author of Karate and I don't understand why there is a need to integrate Karate with QMetry. Maybe you should ask the QMetry team this question.

Comment: @PeterThomas By using QMetry Automation API it will be  able to create cases once the execution completed and these all will display on JIRA itself.Escalated to QMetry support .Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your use case is to upload Karate test results to QMetry Test Management, it's possible. Karate results are similar to Cucumber (BDD) framework and generally the automation test results files could be generated in .json format. QMetry Test Management for Jira (QTM4J) has inbuilt support for Cucumber automation file uploads (supports json format), the test cases, test executions and execution results shall be automatically imported to the QMetry products. You can refer the following resources for uploading the test results to QMetry.

For QMetry Test Management for Jira

- [Upload Automation Test Results to QTM4J using Automation API](https://qmetrysupport.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/QTM4J/pages/1000866944/Import+Results+using+Rest+API)
- [Upload Cucumber Framework Test Results to QTM4J](https://qmetrysupport.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/QTM4J/pages/1000899168/Test+using+Cucumber)

Note - Mostly, the .json results shall be directly uploaded to QMetry. Incase if the result file format do not match the supported format of QMetry, you can write a translator that can convert your results into a QMetry supported format and upload it OR you can take help from QMetry Support - qmetryforjira@qmetrysupport.atlassian.net to create a translator for you. Based on my experience the QMetry support team is very responsive and resourceful.